# magento js and skin are not loading.(404 error)

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404

After `linux` server restart,

To enable magento site, I tried to restart `nginx` service, `php-fpm`.

But I got this error in my magento site.

So I have searched solution to fix this error, tried to many solution,

but I can't fix this error. For example

- in `.htaccess` file confirm rewrite enable
- rename `.htaccess` to `.htaccess-old`
- Update  to `core_config_data` path like `'dev/merge/*' 0`
- confirm my `js/skin` url by
  `Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_JS)`

I just shut down linux server for install telnet...

How I can fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are using Nginx the problem has nothing to do with your .htacess. 
Check in your nginx's config file if you have permissions to access the assets. E.g.:

...

```
location /media/                 { allow all; }
location ^~ /app/                { deny all; }
location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }
location ^~ /docs/               { deny all; }


location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|gif|png|jpeg)$ {
        expires 30d;
        rewrite ^/skin/m/(.+?)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;
}
```

...

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you so much.
I find what problem is.
I wanted to implement magento variable version.
So I rename a public_html to 1.8.1.
Finally magento didn't recognize this folder.
Thank you!!